# insert two object in database with linq

Tags: c#, linq

i have two sql table (master/detail) and i have one method that save the object in sql.
like this:

```
 public int InsertDoc(MymasterModel _inputMstr, string _IsForsale)
    {
    MasterModel _Mstr = new MasterModel();
    InsertDocs ins = new InsertDocs();
    _Mstr.Date = _inputMstr.DocDate;
    .
    .
    .
    ;


    _Mstr.DtlsModel = new List<DtlDataModel>();
            _inputMstr.MyDtlDataModel.ToList().ForEach(d =>
            {
                _Mstr.DtlsModel.Add(new DtlDataModel()
                {
                    Serial = d.Serial.ToString(),
                    Qty = d.Qty,
            ...
                });
            });

    <b>return ins.InsertDoc(_Mstr)</b>;
    }
```

Now i want to save two docs with different type with same detail in sql. (Input and OutPut Doc)
insert this docs Linked to each other like transaction.
how can i do this with linq?
thanks a lot

Comment: Linq does not support Insert/Update/Delete, it is for querying/selecting data only.

Answer (score 0):

As @BenRobinson mentioned up above, you can't do it with LINQ.  LIN**Q** is for **Q**ueries.  You could look at Entity Framework (or another ORM) for doing Updates, Inserts, or Deletes.

EntityFramework would look something like:

```
var details=new details {...}
db.details.Add(details):
db.docs.Add(new doc {... , details=details});
db.docs.Add(new doc {... , detials=details});
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: how can i do this with Entity Framework ? thanks for your help